# Where is archive-dump for Drush 9?

Tags: drush

I have drush 9 installed (current dev release). I can't find the archive-dump command, despite [the docs](https://drushcommands.com/drush-9x/core/archive-dump/) suggesting it should be there.

Executing it produces:

> The Drush command 'archive-dump' could not be found. Use 'drush core-status' to verify that Drupal is found and bootstrapped successfully. Look for 'Drupal bootstrap : Successful' in its output.

I can confirm that `drush core-status` (or `status`) states that Drupal is successfully bootstrapped. The problem is present for local and remote environments, and on any machine that it's installed on (I've tried 4 so far, a mix of MacOS and Ubuntu environments).

I've even gone so far as to grep drush's code for mentions of *archive* and *ard* (the alias that used to work and also should if the docs are to be believed. There doesn't seem to be anything pertinent in there.

So where's archive-dump gone?? If it's been removed, what's its successor?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Turns out it was removed in [this commit](https://github.com/mikeker/drush/commit/39fb2808e7ec053f0d61ca886f56d7e74961c428) to Drush 9 following this [issue](https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/issues/1779) and [follow up](https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/pull/2532).

So archiving no longer exists, or at least not until someone has time to port the logic over to the Composer workflow.

Comment: Grrr. i think having a usable webdir backup with db dumps easily was beneficial, even if the composer workflow files were omitted :(